# How to get parent view control refrence from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a view (name : view1), there are 2 controls. one text box and other date picker. In the same view, i load a partial page (name: view2).

My question is how do i get reference to parent page's (view1) textbox and date picker control from partial page ?

Comment: The partial view is rendered within the parent view. So you have access to the parent controls. Where do you want to reference them, in the JS? Do you get any error if you do so?

Comment: Hi Dennis. thanks for asking. I'm very new to ASP.NET mvc. I don't want to reference them from JS, but from the view code. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you were talking about ASP.NET Webforms code behind files and you would like to access a control in the page via a user control object, you could use

```
Page.[property here]
```

In ASP.NET MVC you can pass data between code and views through the ViewBag property or the Model. Let's say that you have a partial view that has to receive some kind of data. You can define the object type of the data as @model [type] on top, and then pass the object from the main view with

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_name", modelobject)
```

Inside your partial view you can access that data using

```
@Model.[property]
```

Comment: Hi, How do i get reference to parent view control (ex. data grid) from partial view. please suggest

Comment: I can help better if you can provide a code sample of what you are trying to do. Since the views are combined and rendered as a single one to the browser, you can interact with any element on the page client-side using javascript and id/class selectors. But generally speaking, if you are trying to access the parent view from a child view at server-side there is probably a flaw in your design.